# Extracting specific parameter and its amount from a text file

Tags: file-io, fortran, intel-fortran, data-extraction

I have a text file (S.txt) which contains a certain parameter with its amount in each interval. Something like this:

```
-
-
x=a
-
-
x=b
-
-
x=c
-
-

.
.
.
```

I want to write Fortran code to open the text file (S.txt) and read it in order to find each 'x' and read its amount into a parameter. something like this:

a

b

c

.
.
.

I have come up with this code but it does not work:

```
PROGRAM  deter

IMPLICIT  NONE 
real,Dimension(2) :: value
open(unit=40,file='D:\S.txt',action='read')
READ(40,fmt='(2X,f3.3)') value

close(40)

END PROGRAM  deter
```

when I run this program I get NO ERROR, but it doesn't work either.

any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try anything? What sort of problem did you encounter? Are you aware of namelists? They may or may not be helpful.

Comment: Do not use comments for code or other important information. [edit] your question instead and describe what happened when you tried that code. Were there any errors? Which ones?

Comment: You wrote "I have come up with this code but it does not work" what are the problems, the source code does not look like correct Fortran code (`THEN` is on the wrong place). Is it fixed form of free form code ? Is the file opened properly and is it readable? You didn't try to read anything, ...

Comment: What are you trying to say with `IF (x == *) THEN`?  That's not valid Fortran, but to say what you need instead requires context.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have correct it but I still get error. Its a free form code.

Comment: The code is very wonky.  Aside from that, there is no `read` statement to get values out of the file; I'd expect to see at least one such statement in this kind of program.  I think you should step away from the keyboard, take a pencil and paper with you, and try to write the program on paper, thinking carefully about each step.  When you've done that, try writing the code again.

Comment: @francescalus by using "IF (x == *) THEN" I wanted Fortran to find and store amounts which were assigned to "x" as I explained in my question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Actually there is a read statement "open(unit=40,file='D:\S.txt',action='read')" . It's been a long time since I have not used FORTRAN for programming so I may  not be good at it but I'm pretty sure the "open " statement with "action='read'" works perfectly.

Comment: The `action=read` specifies the way the file is opened it does no reading of the file contents.

Comment: @francescalus  yes you are right I made a mistake. I forget to include "read" statement.

Comment: There is now a read statement but where does the data go? also there is still the `IF (x == *) THEN` so please reread the comment from High Performance Mark

Comment: You try to read something but further you are not doing anything with it.

Comment: You write that the latest version of the program *doesn't work*.  Are you sure ?  It doesn't really do anything at all; it opens a file, reads two values, then closes the file.  What is it not doing that it should do ?  I refer you back to my original comment.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If the code could have read the data from text file, its enough for me.

Comment: @albert I dont know how to tell fortran that in the text file the parameter x  is an array type real and its amount must be read after equal sign '=' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
program extract_value

implicit none
integer :: ios
character(len=200), allocatable :: command(:)
character(len=200), allocatable :: word(:)
real, allocatable :: x(:), deter(:)
character(len=200) :: line
integer :: n, i, j, r
character (len=5), parameter :: sstr='x='

open(unit=50, file='D:\S.txt', iostat=ios)
if ( ios /= 0 ) stop "Error opening file S.txt"

n = 0

do
    read(50, '(A)', iostat=ios) line
    if (ios /= 0) exit
    n = n + 1
end do

allocate(command(n))
allocate(word(n))
rewind(50)

j=0

do i = 1, n
    read(50,'(A)') command(i)
    read (command(i),'(a2)') word(i)
    if (word(i)==sstr) then
    j=j+1
    end if
end do

allocate(x(n))
allocate(deter(j))

x=0

do i = 1, n
if (word(i)==sstr) then 

read(command(i), fmt='(2X,f5.2)') x(i)

end if
end do 

deter=0
deter=pack(x, x /= 0)
close(50)


open(unit=100, file='D:\R.txt', action="write",status="replace")
WRITE(100,fmt='(2X,f5.2)')(deter(r), r=1,j)
close(100)


end program extract_value
```